# How to modularize directory selector for the golem framework?

Tags: r, session, shiny, volumes, golem

I have been working on a shiny app that I would like to integrate to the golem framework. I used a directory selector from the [shinyFiles package](https://github.com/thomasp85/shinyFiles), but I got some problems trying to modularize it (the shiny app does not show my directories anymore). Have to say I am a beginner to shiny apps development. Any advice is highly appreciated:

```
#' datadir UI Function
#'
#' @description A shiny Module.
#'
#' @param id,input,output,session Internal parameters for {shiny}.
#'
#' @noRd
#'
#' @importFrom shiny NS tagList
mod_datadir_ui <- function(id){
   ns <- NS(id)
   tagList(
     shinyDirButton("datadir", "Raw data directory",
                    "Please select the folder containing the raw accelerometer data")
   )
}

#' datadir Server Function
#'
#' @noRd
mod_datadir_server <- function(input, output, session){
   ns <- session$ns
   volumes <- c(Home = fs::path_home(), "R Installation" = R.home(),
                getVolumes()())

   # DATADIR
   shinyDirChoose(input, "datadir", roots = volumes, session = session,
                  restrictions = system.file(package = "base"))
}

## To be copied in the UI
# mod_datadir_ui("datadir_ui_1")

## To be copied in the server
# callModule(mod_datadir_server, "datadir_ui_1")
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding ns for the id

```
#'
#' @description A shiny Module.
#'
#' @param id,input,output,session Internal parameters for {shiny}.
#'
#' @noRd
#'
#' @importFrom shiny NS tagList
mod_datadir_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    shinyDirButton(ns("datadir"), "Raw data directory",
                   "Please select the folder containing the raw accelerometer data")
  )
}

#' datadir Server Function
#'
#' @noRd
mod_datadir_server <- function(input, output, session){
  ns <- session$ns
  volumes <- c(Home = fs::path_home(), "R Installation" = R.home(),
               getVolumes()())

  # DATADIR
  shinyDirChoose(input, "datadir", roots = volumes, session = session,
                 restrictions = system.file(package = "base"))
}

## To be copied in the UI
# mod_datadir_ui("datadir_ui_1")

## To be copied in the server


library(shiny)
library(shinyFiles)

ui <- fluidPage(
  mod_datadir_ui('jean')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  callModule(mod_datadir_server, "jean")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Looks like it's working now.